# How can I store an array of strings in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a Django data model and I want to be able to store an array of strings in one of the variables; how can I do that?

e.g.

```
class myClass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stringArr = models.???
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make another model that holds a string with an optional order, give it a `ForeignKey` back to `myClass`, and store your array in there.

Comment: Isn't that rather inefficient?

Comment: If you never have to care what the strings are, sure. As soon as you care, you're going to want more structure.

Answer (score 13):

You can use some serialization mechanism like JSON. There's a snippet with field definition that could be of some use to you:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1478/ (take a look at the code in the last comment)

With such field you can seamlessly put strings into a list and assign them to such field. The field abstraction will do the rest. The same with reading.

Comment: I often use JSON serialized data: be aware though that it is an SQL Antipattern http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns, although there are some legitimate uses.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using PostgreSQL or MongoDB(with [djongo](https://www.djongomapper.com/)) you can do this

For PostgreSQL:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
```

For MongoDB(with [Djongo](https://www.djongomapper.com/)):

```
from djongo import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
```

Then

```
stringArr = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),size=8)
```

The above works in both cases.

Comment: hi working with mongodb using same as you said but whne i do an update i am getting SQLDecodeError at /admin/dataIngestionAPI/submissionfields/1/change/
FAILED SQL: UPDATE "dataIngestionAPI_submissionfields" SET .... can you please help

Comment: This is postgresSQL specific model field, you cannot use it with mongodb

Comment: It works well if you are using the Djongo driver. Notice the models import is from djongo and not Django. Djongo allows easy switching between different types of database with minimal changes in models

Answer (score 5):

I did this for my model and it worked

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models


class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
```

To create

```
Skill.objects.create(name='First name', skills=['thoughts', 'django'])
```

To Query

```
Skill.objects.filter(skills__contains=['thoughts'])
```

You can refer to the django documentation for more help

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

You can use cPickle...

```
class myClass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stringArr = models.TextField()

from cPickle import loads, dumps
data = [ { 'a':'A', 'b':2, 'c':3.0 } ]
obj = Myclass.objects.get(pk=???)
# pickle data into a string-like format
obj.stringArr = dumps(data)
obj.save()
# restore original data
data = loads(obj.stringArr)
```

Comment: You can also generalise this to a PickleField, or use the one on pypi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSONField` for such functionality:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class TestModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    strings = JSONField(default=list, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

for example:

```py
In [1]: fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']                                                                                                                                         

In [2]: TestModel.objects.create(title='my set', strings=fruits)                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: <TestModel: my set>

In [3]: o = TestModel.objects.first()                                                                                                                                                  

In [4]: o.strings                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[4]: ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```