# Djongo redefine the structure of ArrayModelField

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I am defining [ArrayModelField](https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/array-model-field/) using [Djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/). It looks great, but the problem with `ArrayModelField` is I can only add it as **Array of Objects**, not just **Flat List**. Is there any way by which I can add it as **Flat List**?

**Example:**

```
# models.py
from djongo import models

class Option(models.Model):
    option = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.option

class Quiz(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    options = models.ArrayModelField(model_container=Option)
    answers = models.ArrayModelField(model_container=Option)
```

Using this I can create a document as follows,

[image: Current Document Format]

But I want to save it in this format,

[image: Required Document Format]

I want the view to be parsed in **Django Admin Panel** too.

Is there any way by which I can do this now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you need a separate model if that's the format you want. Why not a simple ArrayField?

Comment: I think ArrayField is Postgres specific. Anyway, I can't find **ArrayField** inside Djongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of latest version in Djongo, this structure is still not possible if you want to have automatic support for Admin Panel. Having said that, you can always use `ListField` and write custom view for the admin panel which is a valid solution for now. Also don't see any timeline in which that will be fixed by the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListField:

`options = models.ListField()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Cob. Unfortunately, I think, this doesn't get parsed in Django Admin Panel. I want this to be viewed in Admin Panel.

Comment: To ba able to view it in admin panel you have to define ModelForm class. here you can see how to do it: https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/list-field/

Comment: Yep! But ModelForm class was not working if it's a flat list.

Comment: You are right. I had the same problem recently, but switched to ArrayField and it seems to work fine. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53811152

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cob! Will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, where the database connected is a MongoDB, you can do this:

```
from djongo import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Option(models.Model):
.
.
.

class Quiz(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    options = models.ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True),size=8)
```

this will show your options in a comma-separated manner i.e. A,B,C
[attaching a screenshot for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSSfs.png)